# How to get length of elements in a loop with specific style property values

Tags: javascript, css

How can I get the length of the elements of loop which has the inline style property opacity value '1' in pure javascript. I want to capture them with inline style property values only but not with assigning any classNames because for future purpose i may want to capture them with different attribute values 
 or different style property values too. Is there any chance of getting the elements by using something like this `document.querySelectorAll("li[style*='opacity:1']")`

```
<ul id="all" class="select">
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
   <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
</ul>
<script>
   var elem = document.querySelectorAll("li");

   // var elem = document.querySelectorAll("li[style*='opacity:1']");

         for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
             if(elem[i].style.opacity == 1){
                 console.log(elem[i].length);
             }
         }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'length', __number of items__ with opacity = 1 or __summary width__ of such elements?

Comment: I mean Number of items with opacity = 1 . When I find the length with opacity 1 then I will target those li elements creating in new  loop and changing  dynamically the width or anything

Comment: Than @mankowitz answer should do the trick
`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li")).filter(el => parseInt(el.style.opacity)).length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this? It's not that much better than what you have.

```js
var elem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li")).filter(el => el.style.opacity == 1);

console.log (elem.length);
```

```html
<ul id="all" class="select">
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 0; display:inline-block;">text</li>
  <li class="someclass" style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;">text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('li[style="opacity: 1; display:inline-block;"]');
```

Considering every element has `display:inline-block;` too.

Comment: Its working only if 'display:inline-block' is added with opacity too. If I try with only 'li[style="opacity: 1;"]' why its not working.